# Calling function to execute javascript code

Tags: javascript, adsense

I would like to place a javascript (adsense) code inside the post (not above or after the post). It will be a HTML page.

Is there any way i can put my adsense code in external Js file and i will use one function to display it.
adsense code looks something like

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_host = "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

So if i  call a function  `CallMe()` which will start showing ad wherever i have used the function. In future if i would like to replace ad code with another code then i dont want to go to each post and replace it.  I will just replace the adcode from js file.

I am a newbie and have just started learning JavaScript so i am really not aware if it can be done or not.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create file called `AdSense.js` with the following code:

```
google_ad_client = "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_host = "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
function ApplyAdSense() {
    var oScript = document.createElement("script");
    oScript.type = "text/javascript";
    oScript.src = "http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(oScript);
}
```

Now whenever you want adsense in your code, first include the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="AdSense.js"></script>
```

Then call the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ApplyAdSense();
</script>
```

This way, until you call the function nothing happens.. and you can also comment the code inside the function to disable adsense throughout all your site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer..Let me try this first.. I will let you know if its working or not..

Comment: I have uploaded file on the sites.google.com and put `<script type="text/javascript" src="www.sites.google.com/sites/xyz/adsense.js"></script>` (not a real path)..and used code in the HTML file as follows: `script type="text/javascript" src="www.sites.google.com/sites/xyz/adsense.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    ApplyAdSense();
</script>` Is it right ?

Comment: Can i use the complete code in <body> </tags> or i need to put something inside <head></head> ?

Comment: can i ask u something ? Have u used such method for your site? I tried but it only shows black space instead of ad..I think i should not play with adsense code because changing the adsense code is not allowed as per the adsense terms.. :-) Thanks anyways. I learned few things today.

Comment: They're probably using `document.write` so it's a dead end, sorry.. you'll have to put it in every page. However if you have server side language at your disposal it might make your life easier. Is there?

Comment: Nope..M using Blogger so no control over server side.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want the ad to show up, place this code (assuming you have a function called CallMe).

```
    <some html>
        <script type="text/javascript">CallMe();</script>
    </some html>
```

Comment: Nope. callMe() was just an example... Do i need to put the code in the JS File?

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is about the page loading time, Adsense released the asynchronous version of their Adsense code. Please see https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en